# Can I concatenate text / html files with some soft of batch file?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

On windows I could do something like...

copy /b file1+file2 file3

copy /b file1+file4 file5

In one batch file to generate a files made up of several files.

I've trying to create some html help files, with a header, footer, unique content and files containing common content.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
cat file1 file4 >> file5
```

file3 and file5 are the output files, just list the files you want to concatenate in order of how they should appear in the output files.

Comment: Can I put these in a batch file ? if so how ?

Comment: Yes, just create a file, put those exact lines in it and run it with: sh <filename>